# How to disable JavaScript Function when other function is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slider

**Hi,**

I'm learning/practicing to make my custom slider in JS/JQuery, and I've written below code. Its almost running well but little issues. What I'm doing is I'm running it two types,

1. Auto running after each 5 seconds with autoRun() Function
2. On every click to slider indicator run to relevant slide with click event.

In below code, I'm facing couple of issues, *and will be very thankful to you if you help me.*

**Issues I'm facing are:**

1. When I click to slider indicator, I want to disable auto Run function for a specific time like 5 second so my slider look more professional.
2. When it goes to last slide or come back to first slide, console is showing an error below, and it also take double time eg: 10 seconds to go next slide.

   **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined"**

```js
$(function () {
    var $mainSliderWrap = $('#slider_main_wrapper')
        , $sliderMain = $mainSliderWrap.find('.main-slider')
        , $sliderchildren = $sliderMain.children('li')
        , $sliderIndicator = $mainSliderWrap.find('.slider-main-indicator');
    // Slider Setup
    window.addEventListener('resize', initMainSlider);
    initMainSlider();
    
    // Slider SetUp function
    function initMainSlider() {
        var wWidth = window.outerWidth
            , sliderMainWidth = wWidth * $sliderchildren.length
        $sliderMain.css('width', sliderMainWidth + 'px');
        $sliderMain.children('li').first().addClass('visible');
        $sliderIndicator.children('li').first().addClass('active');
    }
    // Want to Run Slider on Click event
    $sliderIndicator.on('click', 'li', updateMainSlider);
    // If Click Event Not happenening then I want to auto run Slider after 5 seconds
    autoRun()

    function autoRun() {
        var mainSliderChildLenght = $sliderchildren.length;
        var i = 0;
        var next = true;
        var dir;
        setInterval(function () {
            if (mainSliderChildLenght == i || i < 0) {
                next = !next;
                if (i < 0) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
            if (next) {
                dir = 'next';
                i++;
            }
            else {
                dir = 'prev';
                i--;
                if(i < 0) {
                    return
                }
            }
            updateMainSlider(dir);
            $('#result').text(i)
        }, 5000);
    }
    // Here is the function for Updating the Slider
    function updateMainSlider(a) {
        var visibleSlide = $sliderchildren.filter('.visible')
            , actualTranslate = getTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'X');
        if (a == 'next' || a == 'prev') { // inside this if is running when function is called from autoRun()
            console.log(a)
            var newSlide = (a == 'next') ? visibleSlide.next() : visibleSlide.prev()
                , newSlideOffsetLeft = newSlide.offset().left
                , valueToTranslte = -newSlideOffsetLeft + actualTranslate;
            
            setTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'translateX', valueToTranslte);
            
            visibleSlide.removeClass('visible');
            newSlide.addClass('visible');
            $sliderIndicator.children('.active').removeClass('active');
            $sliderIndicator.find('li').eq(newSlide.index()).addClass('active');
        }
        else { // inside this if is running when function is called from click event
            console.log(a)
            var newSlide = $(a.target)
                , $newSlideIndicatorIndex = newSlide.index()
                , $visibleSlideIndex = visibleSlide.index();
            if ($newSlideIndicatorIndex !== $visibleSlideIndex && !$($sliderIndicator).hasClass('disable-click')) {
                $($sliderIndicator).addClass('disable-click');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $($sliderIndicator).removeClass('disable-click');
                }, 1000);
                var diff = $newSlideIndicatorIndex - $visibleSlideIndex
                    , valueToTranslte = -(diff * window.outerWidth) + actualTranslate;
                
                setTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'translateX', valueToTranslte);
                
                $($sliderchildren[$visibleSlideIndex]).removeClass('visible');
                $($sliderchildren[$newSlideIndicatorIndex]).addClass('visible');
                $sliderIndicator.children('.active').removeClass('active');
                $sliderIndicator.find('li').eq($newSlideIndicatorIndex).addClass('active');
            } // end if
            
        } // end else
    } // end function
    // SetTranslate Value Fucntion
    function setTranslateValue(element, property, value) {
        $(element).css({
            'transform': property + '(' + value + 'px)'
        });
    }
    // Get Translate Value function
    function getTranslateValue(element, axis) {
        var trValue = $(element).css('transform');
        if (trValue !== 'none') {
            trValue = trValue.split(')')[0];
            trValue = trValue.split(',');
            trValue = (axis == 'X') ? trValue[4] : trValue[5];
        }
        else {
            trValue = 0;
        }
        return Number(trValue);
    }
})
```

```css
        ol {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .slider-main-wrapper {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px orange;
            min-height: 100vh;
        }
        
        ol.main-slider {
            height: 85vh;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px green;
            transition: transform 500ms ease;
        }
        
        ol.main-slider > li {
            float: left;
        }
        
        ol.main-slider > li .silder-main-content {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 85vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        ol.main-slider > li.visible .silder-main-content {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 140px green;
        }
        
        ol.slider-main-indicator {
            height: 15vh;
            display: flex;
        }
        
        ol.slider-main-indicator li {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px green;
            flex: 1;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        ol.slider-main-indicator li.active {
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px green;
            cursor: default;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result" style="font-size: 30px; position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0"></div>
    <div class="slider-main-wrapper" id="slider_main_wrapper">
        <ol class="main-slider">
            <li>
                <div class="silder-main-content">
                    <h1>First Slide</h1>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="silder-main-content">
                    <h2>Second Slide</h2>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="silder-main-content">
                    <h1>Third Slide</h1>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="silder-main-content">
                    <h1>Fourth Slide</h1>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <!--end slides-->
        <ol class="slider-main-indicator">
            <li> <span class="text">First Slide</span> </li>
            <li> <span class="text">Second Slide</span> </li>
            <li> <span class="text">Third Slide</span> </li>
            <li> <span class="text">Fourth Slide</span> </li>
        </ol>
        <!--end slide indicator-->
    </div>
```

Comment: Any Change help in customization in code will also be appreciated and I know this code should be shorten so looking for someone who will do it too. Thanks

Comment: If you want to stop a function executing while a different function is running you could use a global variable `var running=false` and with each execution change that variable to `true` and at the end of the script set it to `false` this way you can always check if that variable is `true/false` to know if the function is running....

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to clearInterval when you click, the setInterval again once the processing due to the "click" event completes - so, for a start, you'll need to save the returned value of `setInterval` to use in `clearInterval`

`autoRun` in this code returns a function which starts the interval

this is just "part" of your code, not the whole thing - trying to keep it readable regarding the changes I have implemented

```
$sliderIndicator.on('click', 'li', updateMainSlider);
// save the function returned by autoRun
var go = autoRun();
// start autoRun
go();
// add a variable to store interval identifier
var interval;
function autoRun() {
    var mainSliderChildLenght = $sliderchildren.length;
    var i = 0;
    var next = true;
    var dir;
    // return a function to begin autoRun for real
    return function() {
        // save interval identifier
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            // your code unchanged
        }, 5000);
    };
}
function updateMainSlider(a) {
    var visibleSlide = $sliderchildren.filter('.visible')
        , actualTranslate = getTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'X');
    if (a == 'next' || a == 'prev') {
        // your code - unchanged
    } else {
        // clear interval
        clearInterval(interval);
        // your code - unchanged
        // now add this to restart the interval
        go();
    }
}
```

You may still need to tweak some things, I haven't gone through your code in depth

---

> as requested

```
$(function () {
    var $mainSliderWrap = $('#slider_main_wrapper')
        , $sliderMain = $mainSliderWrap.find('.main-slider')
        , $sliderchildren = $sliderMain.children('li')
        , $sliderIndicator = $mainSliderWrap.find('.slider-main-indicator');
    // Slider Setup
    window.addEventListener('resize', initMainSlider);
    initMainSlider();

    // Slider SetUp function
    function initMainSlider() {
        var wWidth = window.outerWidth
            , sliderMainWidth = wWidth * $sliderchildren.length
        $sliderMain.css('width', sliderMainWidth + 'px');
        $sliderMain.children('li').first().addClass('visible');
        $sliderIndicator.children('li').first().addClass('active');
    }
    // Want to Run Slider on Click event
    $sliderIndicator.on('click', 'li', updateMainSlider);
    // If Click Event Not happenening then I want to auto run Slider after 5 seconds
    var go = autoRun();
    // start autoRun
    go();
    var interval;

    function autoRun() {
        var mainSliderChildLenght = $sliderchildren.length;
        var i = 0;
        var next = true;
        var dir;
        return function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                if (mainSliderChildLenght == i || i < 0) {
                    next = !next;
                    if (i < 0) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (next) {
                    dir = 'next';
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    dir = 'prev';
                    i--;
                    if(i < 0) {
                        return
                    }
                }
                updateMainSlider(dir);
                $('#result').text(i)
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
    // Here is the function for Updating the Slider
    function updateMainSlider(a) {
        var visibleSlide = $sliderchildren.filter('.visible')
            , actualTranslate = getTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'X');
        if (a == 'next' || a == 'prev') { // inside this if is running when function is called from autoRun()
            console.log(a)
            var newSlide = (a == 'next') ? visibleSlide.next() : visibleSlide.prev()
                , newSlideOffsetLeft = newSlide.offset().left
                , valueToTranslte = -newSlideOffsetLeft + actualTranslate;

            setTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'translateX', valueToTranslte);

            visibleSlide.removeClass('visible');
            newSlide.addClass('visible');
            $sliderIndicator.children('.active').removeClass('active');
            $sliderIndicator.find('li').eq(newSlide.index()).addClass('active');
        }
        else { // inside this if is running when function is called from click event
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log(a)
            var newSlide = $(a.target)
                , $newSlideIndicatorIndex = newSlide.index()
                , $visibleSlideIndex = visibleSlide.index();
            if ($newSlideIndicatorIndex !== $visibleSlideIndex && !$($sliderIndicator).hasClass('disable-click')) {
                $($sliderIndicator).addClass('disable-click');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $($sliderIndicator).removeClass('disable-click');
                }, 1000);
                var diff = $newSlideIndicatorIndex - $visibleSlideIndex
                    , valueToTranslte = -(diff * window.outerWidth) + actualTranslate;

                setTranslateValue($sliderMain, 'translateX', valueToTranslte);

                $($sliderchildren[$visibleSlideIndex]).removeClass('visible');
                $($sliderchildren[$newSlideIndicatorIndex]).addClass('visible');
                $sliderIndicator.children('.active').removeClass('active');
                $sliderIndicator.find('li').eq($newSlideIndicatorIndex).addClass('active');
            } // end if
            go();
        } // end else
    } // end function
    // SetTranslate Value Fucntion
    function setTranslateValue(element, property, value) {
        $(element).css({
            'transform': property + '(' + value + 'px)'
        });
    }
    // Get Translate Value function
    function getTranslateValue(element, axis) {
        var trValue = $(element).css('transform');
        if (trValue !== 'none') {
            trValue = trValue.split(')')[0];
            trValue = trValue.split(',');
            trValue = (axis == 'X') ? trValue[4] : trValue[5];
        }
        else {
            trValue = 0;
        }
        return Number(trValue);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, I'm trying to do with your described method, but it is not happening for me. Can you please give me full code for this. I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: OK, updated answer - if it doesn't work, check the developer tools console for any errors